# CSS @font-face not working in my CMS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

This is the code I am using.

```
@font-face {
font-family:gotisch;
src:url('__cmsurl__/files/www/dscaslongotisch.ttf') format:('truetype');
}
h1{
    font-family:gotisch;
}
```

the source is correct, the CMS automatically sets the url, but the font is not displayed in neither Chrome nor Firefox.

When I do use this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:gotisch;
    src:url('__cmsurl__/files/www/dscaslongotisch.ttf') format:('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: gotisch_IE;
    src:url('__cmsurl__/files/www/dscaslongotisch.eot');
}

h1{
    font-family:gotisch, 'gotisch_IE';
}
```

it is working in IE, but still not in Firefox / Chrome

Firebug even shows me, that the font is loaded and I can change it to e.g. Verdana - but still, this one is just not displayed. I even tried fontsquirrel, but even then it did not display the font. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) you can see that the fonts you provide (ttf and eot) are for IE, Safari, Android, iOS.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Convert the font to woff and include it like below if you want it to work in Firefox and Chrome.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'gotisch';
  src: url('path_to/gotisch.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('path_to/gotisch.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('path_to/gotisch.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('path_to/gotisch.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

Then use it like this

```
selector {
  font-family: 'gotisch';
}
```